# How to simplify conditional expression in v-bind?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to simplify conditional expression in v-bind?

```html
:href="type === 'exampleType'?`${link}/${id}?exampleGetParam=true`:`${link}/${id}`"
```

not to repeat it `${link}/${id}`

Answer (score 2):

An alternative is to move it to a method for clarity, but probably overkill for this small amount of logic:

```
   methods: {
     buildHref(link, id, type) {
       const href = `${link}/${id}`

       if (type === 'exampleType') {
         return `${href}?exampleGetParam=true`
       }

       return href
     }
   }
```

Use:

```
   :href="buildHref(link, id, type)"
```

Comment: I actually think this is **the** answer - it's more readable than having it the markup

Answer (score 1):

You can put statements in `${}` not just variable names

So: like this

```
:href="`${link}/${id}${type === 'exampleType' ? '?exampleGetParam=true' : ''}`"
```

Comment: Your original suggestion was like ```"`${link}/${id}${type === 'exampleType' && 'exampleGetParam=true`}"```, the ternary operator condition is my suggestion

Comment: I realised my code was in error, as it would not work properly, so I put the ternary operator **from the question** back into my answer - don't start throwing accusations around, @BoussadjraBrahim - your attempted answer had NO bearing on my answer which preceded yours anyway

Answer (score 0):

Try to wrap the whole expression with string template :

```html
<a :href="`${link}/${id}${type === 'exampleType'?'?exampleGetParam=true':''}`" />
```